# Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

I am trying to use `Python Cassandra Driver`, `Batches`, and `PreparedStatements`. I am trying to insert 100k records, but get the following error:

```
E   ValueError: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements.
```

How can I divide the records into chunks and insert them separately? My code is:

```
insert_records = session.prepare("INSERT INTO sample_table (key1, key2, key3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")

batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)

no_of_rows = df_100k.shape[0]  # df_100k is a dataframe contains 100k rows

for row in range(no_of_rows):
    batch.add(insert_records, [df_100k.iloc[row]['key1'], df_100k.iloc[row]['key2'], df_100k.iloc[row]['key3']])

session.execute(batch)
```

UPDATE1
I have tried `execute_async` like this,

```
for row in range(no_of_rows):
    session.execute_async("INSERT INTO invoices (key1, key2, key3) VALUES (df_100k.iloc[row]['key1'], df_100k.iloc[row]['key2'], df_100k.iloc[row]['key3']")
```

but no rows were inserted into the table, what's the issue here?

UPDATE2
The problem was that I forgot to use prepared statement `session.prepare` when using `session.execute_async`.

`execute_async` does resolve my problem with `Batches`, and give a significant performance improvement.

Comment: Why do you have a need to use batch statements? I think it is a misuse of batches.
Please check this article https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/
If you have a need to perform 100k inserts, execute_async driver method is more suitable for you than batch statements: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/3.0/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev I have modified the OP, I have tried `execute_async `, but it didn't work

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev I have solved the problem see OP, I forgot to use prepared statement.